# how to stop the react button to scroll to the bottom on click

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a button that when i click on it its supposed to go to another page and it works, but as soon as it navigates to another page it shows the page from the bottom even tho it should show the beginning of the page. how can I fix it?
  `<button className="btn" onClick={() => handleSeeMoreClick('/project')}>See more</button>`
how can I fix this?

Comment: Please add the code in `handleSeeMoreClick` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your handleseemore click you can add window.scrollTo(0, 0); which will scroll to top